# How to to get EnvironmentObject/Publishers in UI Testing in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, unit-testing, testing, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to write UI Test for SwiftUI sign page with tries to check a publisher from a class if the variable is toggled from `false` to `true`. What I have done is to import the app as module `@testable import MyApp` then wrote this code as bellow;

```
func testLogInOfAUser() throws {
    let email = app.textFields["email"]
    email.tap()
    email.typeText("email@mail.com \n")
    let password = app.secureTextFields["password"]
    password.tap()
    password.typeText("password \n")
    let loginBtn = app.buttons["Login"]
    loginBtn.tap()
    
    let sut = UserAuth()
    sut.login()

    XCTAssert(sut.isLoggedin == true)
    
}
```

Class for `UserAuth`

```
class UserAuth: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoggedin:Bool = false
    
    func login() {
        self.isLoggedin.toggle()
    }
}
```

When I run the test I run into this error;

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "type metadata accessor for MyApp.UserAuth", referenced from:
      MyAppUITests.MyAppUITests.testLogInOfAUser() throws -> () in MyAppUITests.o
  "MyApp.UserAuth.__allocating_init() -> MyApp.UserAuth", referenced from:
      MyAppUITests.MyAppUITests.testLogInOfAUser() throws -> () in MyAppUITests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: There is no need to write `== true `

Answer (score 0):

XCTest is a black-box testing framework.
Thus, you can only interact with an app the way your users interact with it.

In your case, you should check UI changes like if the new screen has appeared after the login and so on.

If you still need to dig into your app, you should use white-box testing frameworks. I recommend you to use EarlGrey 2.0 because it is completely compatible with XCTest and you can retain all your existing code.